# Display label based on, field on one data-source (singular) being within another data-source fields many

Tags: google-app-maker

I am still learning, and looking for help on how to display a label based on one data-sources field value, being within another data-sources field value list.

I have one calculated table, displaying rows of documents within a folder, and wish to use a field representing the document number in that data-source, so that if it's ANYWHERE within another tables field it displays my label.

I've been trying to use projection as I think this is how to achieve it.

I can get it working based on both the current `@datasouce.item.fieldnames` but need it to base the calculation on all possible numbers in that tables field  (Image below should make it easier to understand).

I expect that it has something to do with projections, but can't find anything within the learning templates or anywhere else to resolve the issue.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEsdi.png]

Comment: Does your table B display all records from that model or is there a query size limit? How is your table B generated, does it reload the data in B each time you select a different item in table A? Have you considered making the label a field in your calculated datasource and then displaying 'Reserved' based on how you generate your data inside your calculated model?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work for you. For the 'Reserved' label have the following binding for the text property:

```
(@datasources.project_quotes.items..quotenumber).indexOf(@widget.datasource.item.Qnumber) !== -1 ? 'Reserved' : ''
```

I would suggest alternatively just to include a field in your calculated datasource and making the determination in your server script.

Comment: Hi Markus,
Yes table B does display all records, no limit applied.
B datasource currently loads with the page + triggered when new rows are created.

(@datasources.project_quotes.items..quotenumber).indexOf(@widget.datasource.item.Qnumber) !== -1 ? 'Reserved' : ''

Dont think it likes  '.indexOf' as not allowing me to okay it. I can read and understand your statement apart from indexOf and how its working, so good opportunity for me to go read up  learn, what this does as said learning and not used index's yet.

will return and update with my solution, thank you for direction sir.

Comment: @PJM That is interesting that it won't let you OK the binding. I wonder however, I have run into a glitch before, where I was trying to change the binding on an existing label and it would not let me OK that change either. I then just created a new label with the exact same binding and it let me do that, and I deleted the old label. Might be worth a shot if you have not tried that. Anyway I just tested a similar binding in my own app and it worked also. So definitely try the new label trick.

Comment: Now understand the index and have some speed improvements for my time, and understand your code 100%, so should work, and YES it NEEDED A NEW LABEL CREATED for whatever reason? but it worked Thank you.l